# Efficient way to mark detected faces

Tags: qt, opencv

I'm working on a small detection application using OpenCV and Qt.

my question is: what is the efficient way to mark the detected faces with rectangle knowing that I want this rectangles to be clickable in order to trigger some event for each clicked rectangle.

I've made this using a QPushButton ( with transparent background and some colored border) over a QLabel ( that contains the image ).

[image: My actual render]

is there any other obvious way (maybe QSvg or QGraphicsView) ?

Comment: In QML you could just use any Rect being clicked. For QtGUI you solution having a QPushButton seems to be fine. Eventually you could subclass the pushbutton and implement the paint function to only draw a border (would be faster than transparent background) or you use a subclass of QFrame and reimplement mouseEvent handler to handle your clicks.

Comment: There are dozens of fine ways to achieve clickable rectangles on top of image in Qt. If you have no problem (like some visual or functional thing you want but can't easily do) with your current approach, then use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to widgets, then your current approach is the most obvious. If there can potentially be hundreds of faces, however, `QGraphicsView` would be more efficient, as it's designed for that.

If you can use Qt Quick, then using [MouseArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html) and [Rectangle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html) within a [Repeater](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) would be the simplest approach. Exposing [C++ code to QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) is really simple, as well.